# java code to display a floating point value in specified format in jasper report

Tags: java, floating-point, jasper-reports, formatted

The value 13.10 is printed as 13.1 in my jasper report , I want to print it as 13.10 itself , How to do it .The corresponding JRXML statement is

```
<textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Float"><![CDATA[$F{temp_bill_tax}]]> 
</textFieldExpression>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using iReport to create your jrxml. Right click your textfield, go to the "Text Field" tab, and in the Pattern combo box you select `#,##0.00`.

Or add the pattern attribute in the field:

```
<textField ... pattern="#,##0.00"  >
    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Float"><![CDATA[$F{temp_bill_tax}]]>/>
</textField>
```